# Should I have multiple docker-compose files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently, I have about 20 containers in the same docker-compose.yml file. Not all of the containers are related, but it has been set up this way so I could just run `docker-compose up` once to start all of the containers.

Should I be breaking it up into multiple docker-compose files (e.g. one application per docker-compose file, which could include multiple containers like a front-end + database)? Are there any significant drawbacks with having all of your containers in one huge docker-compose file?

Comment: Simple drawback is, it wont be easy to maintain compose file if your application using env var in compose file.

Comment: AFAIK, docker-compose is mostly a tool used during development. If that's the case, it's only a matter of preference and maintainability. IMO, 20 containers ain't _too much_ for a single compose file but that depends on many other factors as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Not all of the containers are related but it has been set up this way
> so I could just run docker-compose up once

If you keep all the container in single `docker-compose.yml` file for the sake of this need, so then better to go for **One project per docker-compose file** instead creating all containers. as you can start multiple compose file at once also.

If you want to start all container then just pass

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.projecta.yml -f docker-compose.projectb.yml  up
```

Or for a single project

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.projecta.yml
```

You can also explore extend option

[Share Compose configurations between files and projects](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)

I will go for **One project per docker-compose file** because

- It will not create unnecessary container
- It will avoid port conflict ( in case two sharing same port)
- Will save compute cost
- Less time to create a docker-compose stack
- More manageable

And the last when validating compose file is really messy as no proper line indication when there is error, so configuration error will only propagate to single project and it will not affect all the other project.

Comment: do multiple compose files make sense? let us say dev version has nginx redis postgres and express api, and prod version only has api and nginx because it uses elasticache and rds? Should you make multiple docker compose files in this scenario?

Comment: in this case, it might make sense as the stack will be different but with extending option, a dev version will contain redis, postgress and the parent file only contain core service that will be required for both env https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services

Answer (score 3):

I actually had a very similar challenge on my current project. That brought me to the idea of writing a small script which I called `docker-compose-profile` (or short: `dcp`). I published this yesterday on GitLab as [docker-compose-profile](https://gitlab.com/michapoe/docker-compose-profile). So in short: I now can start several predefined docker-compose profiles using a command like `dcp -p some-services "up -d"`. A profile may contain a subset of all defined services in your `docker.compose.yml`. With this mechanism it would be easy to start up several sets of services defined separately in a `dcp.yml`.
Feel free to try it out and give some feedback or suggestions for further improvements.

To answer your question ... If all services belong to the same project You might keep them in one file. If not, split it to separate `docker-compose.yml` files.

Comment: In the meantime, profiles have become a feature of docker compose itself: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Comment: That's true but does not address all features of `dcp`. Anyhow this is something really useful!

Answer (score 0):

Another idea to manage several docker-compose file is to extend docker-compose functionalities to control multiple docker-compose.yml configurations.

I made a script about that on github : https://github.com/valerebron/pegaz