# Is it possible into seperate a large docker-compose.yaml into multiple files and still refer each other's services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` with more than 10 services right now and it looks gone fairly large.
7 of them are for TiDB(https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-docker-compose) so can be grouped together into another `docker-compose.yaml`. Some of the rest `depends_on` the TiDB services.

I wanted to move them to a subdirectory and I know we can run them both by explicitly giving path of the yaml files. Is it possible to run them implicitly using just `docker compose up` command.

Also, is there a way to refer to the services of 2nd yaml in first by some kind of import statement in yaml? Use case is to continue using `depends_on`.

Note: Might seem duplicate of [Docker Compose: Should I have multiple docker-compose files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871280/docker-compose-should-i-have-multiple-docker-compose-files) but it's not.

Comment: As noted in an answer to that linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872435/147356), you can have multiple compose files, but you need to refer to them all explicitly with `-f <filename>` arguments whenever you run a `docker-compose` command (and these multiple files can refer to each other's services). There is no implicit loading nor any sort of "import" statement in the compose syntax.

Comment: Got it. Any comments about 2nd half of the question?
Is there a way to tell docker that Service-A on from yaml depends on Service-B from another yaml?

Comment: You can use depends_on as long as the containers are in the same network